# how do i optionally include a package in setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, setup.py

I have the requirement to install a package, only if its present, and if not, dont fail via setup.py
I have tried via adding in extras_require, but that dosen't seem to do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"to install a package, only if its present"* — if it's present where?

Comment: if present inside the network. For example we are trying to open-source something, so I want to only install a lib, if its called inside the network. Hence i am not placing it in install_requires